# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac{1}{n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin \dfrac{1}{n}$ converge or diverge?

Comment: Duplicate of [Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(1/n)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9867/462).

Comment: Comparison test and integral test don't appear to work for it

Comment: (re-opened and re-closed because of a typo in the question number of the previous closure target)

Answer (score 5):

Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$
so $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
so the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is divergent by comparison with the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$
\forall x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] : \frac{2x}{\pi} \le \sin x 
$$

Hence:
$$
\frac{2}{\pi n} \le \sin\frac{1}{n}
$$

Since $\sum 1/n$ diverges, $\sum \sin 1/n$ diverges too.