# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(\frac1{a_n})$ - General case

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_n)$ converges and if it converge absolutely if we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely.

You can rephrase the question asking if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(\frac1{n^2})$ converges.

**Edit:** I thought this was basically like the general case, but was pointed out it was not.

I found this: 
[Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(1/n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9867/convergence-divergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-sin1-n) But it's for 1/n.

I'm pretty sure that it doesn't converge absolutely because it's a periodic function. As for regular convergence, I'm not really sure how to check.

Note: we can't use integrals because we haven't covered that.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you already use $\lvert \sin x\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: Goes down fast enough, so converges.  Absolutely, but the terms are positive, so that says nothing more. And actually it will show no periodicity, all angles will be between $0$ and $1$,

Comment: @GinKIN is it collected from NET model queston?

Comment: Nope, no idea what that is.

Comment: When you say, "you can rephrase the question..." don't you mean, "we can consider the special case of ...?" The general case certainly doesn't follow from the case $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Also, "because it's a periodic function..." What is a periodic function, $\sin(x)$? Why would that matter?

Comment: @DanielFischer do you know what it's called, I would like to see the proof, beacuse in the linked question you can do this: $\sin(\frac1{n})\le\frac1{n^2}\le\frac1{n}$. $\frac1{n^2}$ we know converge, but $\sin(\frac1{n})$ diverge.

Comment: $\sin \left(\frac1n\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{n^2}$ is wrong for $n \geqslant 2$. You have $x - \frac{x^3}{6} \leqslant \sin x \leqslant x$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I assumed that basically any converging series behaves like $\frac1{n^2}$. Can you elaborate on the general case ? (I'll edit the question for the general case now) About the periodic function, what I meant is that $\sin x$ doesn't go to a certain value but rotate between 1 and -1, from my intuition I think that if we take the absolute value of $sin$, it will rotate but twice over the positive side, so the terms will "stack" and won't cancel each other and it will diverge.

Comment: Regarding periodicity: You are only looking at the values of $\sin x$ in a range near $0$, it doesn't matter at all that the function is periodic. If this is true or false, it depends only on the behavior of $\sin x$ near $0$. @GinKin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the series is converges absolutely

if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin a_n$ also converges absolutely

$$0\le |\sin a_n| \le |a_n|$$